# How do I add an existing angular project as a standalone TypeScript Angular Template project to a solution in Visual Studio 2022 preview?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 preview come with the new feature that it can create a standalone TypeScript Angular Template project. Is there a way that I can import an existing angular project (which doesn't have a *.esproj file) created by angular cli?